# How can I identify the classname of a specific item/engram in ARK?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

As an administrator, I require to identify the classname of the engram of the **[Offline Raid Protection (ORP)](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=600705968)** mod item to hide it for players, however the author of this mod didn't gave that basic and needed info for admins, so... I don't know what can I do now.

I'm not sure whetther maybe I need to install and use Unity and/or maybe a related reverse engineering application to determine the classname of the engram...

How can I identify the classname of a specific item/engram in ARK?.

Comment: Would this count as game development? It isn't really about "gaming" but more about understanding things behind the game itself imo

Comment: @54D Maybe you could have reason, or maybe the ARK process itself could provide something to debug this kind of info without entering in a programming point of view of the problem/question. I really don't know, that's why I'm asking for. Thanks for comment!. EDIT: Anyways in that case then this question should be moved to StackOverflow, or which other community?

Comment: You may want to ask on GameDev then, it should be a more suitable place.

Comment: No this isn't a dev question.  It's an admin question.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently see admins set the xp points required to learn an engram they want to reserve for admin use only to an unobtainable amount so that the engram can only be granted by an admin.